# BlueZ/Pybluez - Bluetooth LE scan while connected to peripheral

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

Short question: Is it possible to scan for LE devices while periodically connecting to some and reading characteristics a) in general [does the protocol allow it] and b) with the BlueZ stack?

Long question: I'm writing a Python script to scan for LE devices advertising a certain UUID. If one is found, we should connect, read a specific characteristic value (call this `ValueA`), and disconnect. The idea is to maintain a real-time list of what `ValueA`'s are present. I want to be able to spawn a thread that starts the LE scans and collects the advertising events into a thread-safe container. When a new device is discovered, a handler should be fired to read `ValueA`.

My efforts using PyBluez and [BluePy](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy) (to connect to peripherals) have failed. When I use terminal commands (`sudo hcitool lescan --duplicates` and `sudo gatttool -I` followed by the connect and read commands), these fail if I try to connect after I start scanning (scan aborts)

I am confused because I notice that if I am connected to a device via `gatttool` prior to starting an LE scan, I can kick off the scan and continue to read `ValueA` without impacting the scan, but not vice versa.

Any insights or good BlueZ programming documentation would be appreciated. Using BlueZ 4.1 on Ubuntu 14.10 Macbook Pro

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't checked recently, but I don't think PyBluez can do BLE.

Your issue with trying to connect while scanning is a known issue that happens with some hardware.  It's an issue specific to certain hardware.  Essentially you need to stop scanning, make your L2CAP/GATT connection, and then restart scanning...  or buy a different dongle that doesn't have that issue.

All the work I've done with BLE in Python has been to mimic what `hcitool` and `gatttool` does in Python.  It's unfortunate, but there's no library (that I know of) that does BLE yet.  Here's a code snippet that may help you to get started:  [Finding Bluetooth low energy with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23788176/finding-bluetooth-low-energy-with-python/23809773#23809773)

Alternatively, you could interact with Bluez using the DBUS interface it provides.  I've been told that you can't interact with attributes that aren't part of a Bluetooth profile, though.  (So, you can interact with a BLE device that uses the heart-rate profile, but not read a value from an accelerometer)

**EDIT:**  Seems there *is* a library for GATT now:  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gattlib

Comment: Ah, so there's nothing in the Bluetooth specification that precludes this from happening. Have you had success with a particular dongle, or is there a name for this feature that I could search for? What version of BlueZ do you work with, 4.x or 5.x? Also, for peripherals, I've had some success using [bluepy](https://github.com/IanHarvey/bluepy) to discover services and read characteristics.

Comment: Well, it's not specified in the standard so it's up to the hardware manufacturer.  The Iogear GBU521 is able to continue scanning while making connections.  A cheap (most likely fake) CSR I got from China wasn't able to.  You basically just have to test to find out.  If you want your code to be robust, you could shut off scanning temporarily when trying to connect and then turn it back on after a connection has been established.

Comment: Good to know; I am using a cheap CSR from China as well. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, missed one of your questions...  I'm using the 4.101 version because I'm using a 3.4 kernel and can't easily move to a newer kernel.  Bluez 5.X requires a newer kernel, but I can't remember where the cut-off is.